# logic behind implementation of ModelBinding in MVC3

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-3, model-binding

I was having a problem with binding using the HTML extension to create text and hidden fields.  The value was being changed after I returned the view and I didn't know why.  After some reading, I learned that this is by design, and it's supposed to use whatever is inside the model state.

Can anyone explain the logic behind this? I don't see a good reason why you would want a supplied parameter to be replaced with what's in the model state.

**Code**

```
        @Html.Hidden("UpdateMode", "Update")
```

**Result**

```
       <input id="UpdateMode" name="UpdateMode" type="hidden" value="Add" />
```

Comment: With the weakly typed helper methods like `@Html.Hidden()`, the value is a default that will be used if the model/property is null. I'd recommend using the strongly-typed methods like `@Html.HiddenFor(m=> m.UpdateMode)`, and setting the default in the object intializer or controller code.

Comment: I think the logic is that, for example, you could set up the same page for Add/Edit functionality, and pass a `null` model to the page for a new record.